# How do I add a child in one time for each user to under another child firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Topic title may confusing.I have user under `students` child.Also I have `mathlab` child. What I want to do is get every student's id's under the `matlab` child and add some specific children under the `students` child.

So If students in mathlab create "class:"math" , ps:"A" under the `students/id/`.

Here is the firebase structure.

```
{
  "mathlab" : {
    "8SFX6ozygaeYm5s80XwEH15eOvR2" : {
      "opos" : "3395762152383824847.5408566913692403"
    },
    "FouXbMWlPpQfkAHSJ98cRyMGyMq2" : {
      "opos" : "2408503147879014222.4051320981527633"
    },
    "pAB5SPbZ42RkpeyB1vSe7vMgh0V2" : {
      "opos" : "4282105147184071736.7786257557636794"
    }
  },
  "students" : {
    "3fw0j4tY1jMuugWaq9N1DZSPNBh2" : {
      "opos" : "4316375953600111482.6297165447082696"
    },
    "8SFX6ozygaeYm5s80XwEH15eOvR2" : {
      "opos" : "3395762152383824847.5408566913692403"
    },
    "FouXbMWlPpQfkAHSJ98cRyMGyMq2" : {
      "opos" : "2408503147879014222.4051320981527633"
    },
    "UCQanT45dlWDb2ntFITa33pC4h22" : {
      "opos" : "5279089148868706990.4495067048309678"
    },
    "aVoyqW6IcsdJEylwT7uuIyYU87l1" : {
      "opos" : "4668496806381405007.7330624192123722"
    },
    "pAB5SPbZ42RkpeyB1vSe7vMgh0V2" : {
      "opos" : "4282105147184071736.7786257557636794"
    },
    "uDQ7ISmmG7RsbCizNXQIZvysEK22" : {
      "opos" : "1342746957828245395.2663129729855386"
    },
    "xM9U9MjoZUVOcqOVG38SzLrzd1z1" : {
      "opos" : "3998977600021296207.4092046127102224"
    }
  }
}
```

What I've done so far

I collect every id's of students and pushed in an array. But how do I create the childs in one time?

```
    var mathkids = [];
var matstudens1;


    myref.child('mathlab').on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {


           //Get id's

                mathkids.push(data.key);



        });
        console.log(mathkids); 
    });



    }
```

Here is what must look like.

```
|students
 |8SFX6ozygaeYm5s80XwEH15eOvR2
  |class:"math"
  |ps:"A"
 |5pw4MkVxKob8nXiHojTl61tQQ822
  |class:"math"
  |ps:"A"
 |FeP6H8H0PyVjMDcqwH3zbY0xAxg2
...
|mathlab
 |8SFX6ozygaeYm5s80XwEH15eOvR2
 |5pw4MkVxKob8nXiHojTl61tQQ822
...
```

**Update**

So I get the studen id's and store to "mathkids" array.Here is the how I do to when I push the data.

```
secondref = firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child("students").child(matstudens1);
secondref.on('value' ,function(datasnapshot) {





    secondref.child("class").set("math");
    secondref.child("ps").set("A");





});



}
```

Every time I have to click button change for "matstudens1" value. How do I at once just usign for all "mathkids" ?

Comment: what do you mean `But how do I create the childs in one time`?

Comment: I get id's an array and pushed.Than I progress one by one for each user.Example:  workfonk = firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child("studends").child(mathkids[0]); Than [1],[2].... I need to do in one time for all user.

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish. I think that is in part because the data structure you shared doesn't cover the output you want. Can you edit your question (there's a link right under it), to include the actual JSON from your database (as text, no screenshots needed)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thank you.I edit my post.Some of them students are in mathlab and I want to add some extra child for each of them under the student child.

Comment: I am also not clear on exactly what you are trying to achieve but I will say that you are duplicating most of your data. I think you need to rethink how your database is structured maybe read up on database design, otherwise you are going to be paying Google a lot of money that you don't need to.

Comment: You seem to be talking about an 'atomic' update of the database where all additions happen at the same time, or all fail. Is that correct?

Comment: I get the student ids under the "mathlab"  and storing to an array.And when I use array[0],array[1] when I push the data to firebase.My question is How I push the child's at once ? I updated my post with java example.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say I am still not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. However, I *think* you are trying to carry out a one-time transaction or atomic-update that adds/updates your database in a single call. Then, if somthing goes wrong, the whole transaction fails otherwise it all succeeds....to maintain database integrity.

So, assuming that I am right, here is a node.js cloud function (called by other functions so not exported itself) that I use to delete records or nodes from my Firebase RTDB. The point is that it is an 'atomic update' so it either all works or all fails...data integrity maintained. Where I am using 'null' to remove records, you can use "math", "A", whatever, to add or update records to the appropriate children. You just have to set the correct references for those children. Then the single statement `await databaseRoot.update(atomicUpdate);` executes the whole transaction. Whilst it is an 'update' any records that don't exist are created. You should be able to see how it works from the code snippet even though it is not specific to your database. You then need to work out how you populate `atomicUpdate` from your array.
Hope I have guessed your purpose correctly and this helps. :-)

```js
async function deleteChatThreadStructure(authenticatedUserId, participantId) {
  var databaseRoot = db.ref();
  var chatThreadId = setChatThreadId(authenticatedUserId, participantId);
  var chatsNodeKey = "/chats/" + chatThreadId;
  var chatsParticipantsNodeAuthUserKey = "/chatsParticipants/" + authenticatedUserId + "/" + participantId;
  var atomicUpdate = {
    [chatsNodeKey]: null,
    [chatsParticipantsNodeAuthUserKey]: null,
  };
  try {
    await databaseRoot.update(atomicUpdate);
    console.info("Chat Thread Structure: " + chatThreadId + " deleted!");
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error("Remove Chat Thread Structure " + chatThreadId +
      " failed with " + error.message);
  }
}
```

**Update:**
When I review your 'what it must look like', the list under 'mathlab' are simply keys with no values or  children. You can't do that in Firebase which requires key value pairs. You could therefore store each of those keys with a corresponding value of 'true' to make them k/v pairs which can then be searched for/accessed individually or I think you can store an array as the value against the key 'mathlab'. I have not tried this myself though.

**Further Update:**
I decided to try it. The following code produced this db structure. You need to choose which you prefer and how you would want to handle updates and deletes.
[image]

```
 const List<String> students = [
   "Student 1",
   "Student 2",
   "Student 3",
   "Student 4",
   "Student 5",
   "Student 6",
   "Student 7",
   "Student 8",
 ];

 _atomicUpdate.addAll(
   {
     "/root/mathLabV1": students,
     "/root/mathLabV2/${students[0]}": true,
     "/root/mathLabV2/${students[1]}": true,
     "/root/mathLabV2/${students[2]}": true,
     "/root/mathLabV2/${students[3]}": true,
     "/root/mathLabV2/${students[4]}": true,
     "/root/mathLabV2/${students[5]}": true,
     "/root/mathLabV2/${students[6]}": true,
   },
 );
 // Add to database.
 // This is a batched (atomic) update that either succeeds or all fails
 // both database additions as one transaction.
 // .update will add records when they don't exist (or replace them if they do).
 await _referenceRoot.update(_atomicUpdate);
```

**Update following your comment below**
To check if the student id exists under 'mathLabV2' I would use the following code in Flutter/Dart....you will need to modify its syntax to suite your needs but the concept is the same:

```
_referenceRoot.child("root").child("mathLabV2").child(<your_student_id>).once()
.then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.value != null) {
      <Do your update processing on the 'students' node using <your_student_id>>;
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort.Normally I don't need to automatically update. It's a single time function.I'm not sure to should I use cloud function for that.I'll set as true to the childs with your code.Than I use .equalTo("true") method for get relevant users and create childs whatever I want.Do I get correct ?